# Conversion Personal Account to a Facebook Page: which token use to upload photo on that page?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-page, facebook-access-token, photo-upload

this is my situation: I converted my personal account in a Facebook page (https://www.facebook.com/nextdoorhelp). Now when I logged in FB as the same account I have only a page adminstration panel for that page (that I call pageX). 
I created an app for my website http://nextdoorhelp.it/ndh to allow login with Facebook account. 
I want to use my FB app to allow to upload a user photo to a specific pageX's photo album.
My problem is that I don't know which access token I have to use to do it!
This is my code:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'     => $appId,
        'secret'    => $app_secret,
        'cookie' => true,
        'fileUpload' => true
    )); 

$accessToken = ????;

$post_login_url = "http://nextdoorhelp.it/ndh";

    // Facebook Photo Album ID = 123456789
    $album_id = "123456789";

    // Enable Facebook Upload Support
    $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

    // Share url
    $uri = 'http://nextdoorhelp.it/ndh/pages/share?item=' . $shareurl;

    // Data
$attachment = array(
    'message' => $msg . ' - '.$uri ,
    'image' => '@' .realpath($photo_path),
    'access_token' => $accessToken
);

$data = $facebook->api('/'.$album_id.'/photos', 'post', $attachment);       

$loaded_photo_id = $data['id'];
return $loaded_photo_id;
```

Moreover, I'm admin for the pageX and I tried to use my access token retrieved by a graph-api call to "me/accounts" for pageX but Facebook answered me with an error message "Error: [FacebookApiException] (#120) Invalid album id".

**How can I obtain right access token to upload photo from every users (Facebook users and not)?**
Please help me, I'm becoming crazy!

Comment: Highly unlikely that a request for `/me/accounts` gets answered with an error message concerning album ids …

Comment: Maybe I explained it in wrong way...That error occurs when I call "$facebook->api('/'.$album_id.'/photos', 'post', $attachment);" using the access token obtained as response to a graph-api call https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts 
(with 
"perms": [
        "ADMINISTER",
        "EDIT_PROFILE",
        "CREATE_CONTENT",
        "MODERATE_CONTENT",
        "CREATE_ADS",
        "BASIC_ADMIN"
      ]
)

Comment: Check your access token using the [debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) for if it’s actually a valid page access token. And then, check the album id again for whether it’s actually correct or not. And if so, I’d suggest opening a bug report with Facebook, if all parameters are correct and this is a specific problem concerning pages converted from former user profiles.

Comment: I used debug tool and the access token seems to be valid only for an hour but it's not right for api call post. The error "Invalid album id" is due to the fact that I haven't an album with that id in my personal profile: this id refers to the PageX's album.
I'd like to upload photo to PageX's album from my app (linked to this page that I'm admin)

Comment: Today, I cannot yet find out a solution.
Thanks everybody